# Difference between User.objects.create_user() vs User.objects.create() vs User().save() in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

In the Django documentation, it uses `User.objects.create_user()` to create a user. I am confused, what is the difference between that and `User.objects.create()` and `User().save()` which are the normal ways to create objects of other models

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The most significant difference is that if you supply a password to the `.create()` method, it will be set verbatim on the user, and will not be usable to authenticate the user.

```
>>> user = User.objects.create(username="foo", password="bar")
>>> user.password
'bar'
>>> user.check_password("bar")
False
```

Instead, the `create_user()` method hashes the password argument, which is then.

```
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(username="foo", password="bar")
>>> user.password
'pbkdf2_sha256$120000$2pHBVu3tYYbK$ESG1nbUY2ZhEmstJ7Fzu1DioXmGYXiLw31YDkOGn9E0='
>>> user.check_password("bar")
True
```

See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L145.

Some other 'tidying' is also done. See the rest of the function linked above.

Comment: What if I created a custom user, by extending `models.Model` not `AbstractUser` because I will use `oAuth2`, so I don't need the password field. then, I could use the `create` function safely, right ? `create_user` won't be available because of not extending `AbstractUser`.

Comment: As other users have replied here, the `create_user` method has some other useful features. What you suggest is safe, and you can use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to configure your custom user, but note that it comes with other useful features besides just the password field. Indeed https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/ suggests integrating with the standard `AbstractUser` model. You could always use it for the sake of convention and disregard the password field.

Comment: Thanks, you're so helpful

Comment: A minor thing to note and be aware of is that creating a `User` without the built-in `create_user` function may potentially cause you issues with other functions that depend on the password being encrypted. For example, during testing where you may want to have a user signed in for a specific request e.g [testing with DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication)

Answer (score 6):

`User.objects.create_user()` is a helper function that provides helpful utilities to create a user that otherwise you would have to do yourself. As per the documentation:

> Creates, saves and returns a User
>
> The username and password are set as given. The domain portion of email is automatically converted to lowercase, and the returned User object will have `is_active` set to `True`.
>
> If no password is provided, `set_unusable_password()` will be called.
>
> The `extra_fields` keyword arguments are passed through to the User’s `__init__` method to allow setting arbitrary fields on a custom user model.

Without `create_user()` you could create the functionality yourself using the methods you mentioned, but it provides useful processing and utility.

Answer (score 4):

`create()` and `save()` are generic methods to create a model instance. They don't do anything specific to the User model while `create_user()` method is specific method to create the user.

While creating user with generic methods, the value you set as a password will not be hashed.You need to do it by yourself like this.

```
u = User(username="username")
u.set_password("password")
u.save()
```

Also you can't do the same with `create()` method without an additional database query.

While with the `create_user()` the username and password are set as given and password will be hashed automatically and the returned User object will have `is_active` set to True

Answer (score 1):

You should get the user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
UserModel = get_user_model()
user = UserModel.objects.create(username="Mr Foo", password="bar")
user.save()
```

Or:

```
user = UserModel.objects.create_user("Mr Foo", password="bar")
user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `create_user()` you don't need to save it with `save()`. `create_user()` already saves the user to the database see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30921356)

Comment: This reiterates what OP already states in the question.