# check password always returns false django

Tags: django, authentication, password-hash

I work with django and store user passwords as hashed values created with make_password. When I run check_password, I always get a false return and I am out of ideas how to solve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My user registration looks like this:

```
def user_reg_view(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        password = hashers.make_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        fname = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        lname = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        company_id = form.cleaned_data.get('company')
        User.objects.create_user(
            email = email,
            password=password,
            first_name = fname,
            last_name = lname,
            username = email,
            company_id = company_id)
        form = UserForm()
    var = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'user_registry.html', var)
```

And my login function part that fails looks like so (assume the user exists and password entered is always the same):

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():

        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        encoded_password =  user.password
        print(hashers.make_password(password) == user.password)
        #returns false
        print(hashers.check_password(password=password, encoded=hashers.make_password(password), setter=None))
        #returns true
        print(hashers.check_password(password=password, encoded=encoded_password))
        # returns false
```

I do not get how the first print differs from the second, of course the password hash generated differs each time for the same string but shouldn't check_password be able to process that?

In case the error might be in the register form values passed, here's also a snippet of that function:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'your company'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'first name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'last name'}))
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=40, label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
        validators=[validate_password],
        label='password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label= 'please confirm password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
        strip=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('password_mismatch')
        return password2
```

Answer (score 1):

Django is hashing the value you provided again when you call `create_user()`, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63055138/7052505), where it says that you can first use `create()` and then `save()` the password as it is, without hashing the value you provide.

Answer (score 1):

The `create_user` method hashes the password that is passed to it as an argument. Meaning you are hashing the plain text password **two times** before storing it to the database. Furthermore no need to use `hashers.check_password` simply use  the [`authenticate` function - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate)

So your registration view would be:

```py
def user_reg_view(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        fname = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        lname = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        company_id = form.cleaned_data.get('company')
        User.objects.create_user(
            email = email,
            password=password,
            first_name = fname,
            last_name = lname,
            username = email,
            company_id = company_id)
        form = UserForm()
    var = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'user_registry.html', var)
```

And your login view:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():

        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user) # login if valid credentials
    # other code
```

Comment: Many thanks! The error was as per usual a minor error I oversaw... I was storing a value that was nonexistent 'password', whereas I should have been storing 'password2' which was returned by my UserForm (registration form)

Answer (score 0):

Double hashing was one of the problems, another one was that I was unknowingly hashing a None value (instead of the actual entered password).

In my registration form (User Form) I work with password1 and password2, after matching them I return password2. In my user_reg_view where I create the user, however, I was setting the password like so:

```
password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
```

This should have been password2 or password1, password was set to None and did not throw an error.